# Simple way to display a session variable in meteorjs

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Is there a simple way just to display a session variable in meteorjs on a page?

It seems like every handlebars outlet (e.g., {{myVar}}) needs to have a Templates.mytemp.myVar = function... or maybe a handlebars helper to display.

So every time you want to show something in HB you have to write a companion display function in meteorjs.

Is that the correct understanding?

Seems cumbersome.

Also, is this an artifact of meteorjs or is it a handlebars need to have access to some variable store to display.  If the latter, maybe I could find and make such a variable place and not use the meteor session store for such things.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way to do it. There are other ways of writing it but at in all of them you would still have to write some sort of companion function as the display logic isn't directly mean't to find its way into HTML & is separated into the helper.

While it is a bit annoying it's still really easy & hardly as cumbersome as it could be, especially with Meteor since the logic right down to the database on the server is all handled for you. It also helps keep code clean & reusable.

If you're using a helper very often and its repetitive you could use a global helper so it can be reused on every template.

A second option is to use a handlebars helper than can take options:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('session', function(name) {
    return Session.get(name);
});
```

Then you could just use

```
{{session "vara"}} {{session "varb"}} {{session "varc"}}
```

And set them with `Session.set` the normal way when you want to change them.

Comment: I could use a little bit more explanation as to how MeteorJS sets the context for the handlebars template.  The handlebars doc notes:var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"}
var html    = template(context);  So if the meteor guys wanted to, they could have the session in the context they pass to it.  Maybe with a namespace like s so you could have {{s.var}} But for now I like this answer better because it explains what you have to do to at the moment to create a solution.  Using the package might do it but obfuscates a bit what really is happening.

Comment: Also does explain there really is no obvious thing that I'm missing that exposes the session to the handlebars context.

Comment: It's `return Session.get(name);` on line 2 (without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You can also give the [handlebar-helpers](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/handlebar-helpers) package a try.

Comment: Package seems useful but in a bit of flux.  Lots of methods are commented with //Deprecating.  Would like to see how this settles down.